Stability of reaction diffusion equation
Consider a scalar reaction diffusion equation
$$
_=_{xx} +()
$$ and suppose that there exist a pulse-type solution, ie a function $_*()$ such that
$$
\begin{cases}
_*'()\ge 0 &\text{for all } x<x_0,\\
_*'()\le 0 &\text{for all } >_0 
\end{cases}
$$
and $_*()\to 0$ exponentially fast  $||\to 0$.
Show that this solution  linearly unstable using the following steps.

Show that the linearization i $_=_{xx} +(_*())$.
Show that $_*'()$   eigenfunction with eigenvalue zero.
Apply Sturm-Liouville theory  the equation $=L$
Explain, using semigroup theory, why this implies that the pulse  linearly unstable.

I have faced a struggle when solving this exercise , i could linearize the given PDE and I've showed that $u_*'$ is an eigenfunction with an eigenvalue zero but once coming to qestion 3 I don't know how to solve it and what's the relation with Sturm Liouville theory. I'd appreciate if anyone provide me with the further steps
